Why are there a priest, deacon, and subdeacon at a High Mass?
Why are there a priest, deacon, and subdeacon at a High Mass? Why not just a priest and deacon? Or just a priest?

The priest, deacon and subdeacon all have their specific role in the High Mass, you can see the different level of activities reflected by the different hierarchical levels. The subdeacon has only received the lower orders (if that is correct English) and isn't allowed to touch certain objects, a deacon can touch. The subdeacon and deacon read from the Bible, but only the deacon may read form the evangelium, and the priest is the only one who may and can perform (again, if this is correct English) the Eucharistic sacrament. So you could say all three are needed. But as a priest can celebrate low Mass alone, the answer could also be:
because if it were only a priest, it would be a low Mass.
In the Novus Ordo the normal setting is priest and deacon, or only priest.
But this may not be the answer you are looking for. Another way to answer your question is that the High Mass has evolved from the Roman papal Mass, where the pope celebrates Mass together with his clergy. In the same way the priest celebrates the High Mass with his clergy: deacon and subdeacon.
I would say the High Mass is the most elaborate form of Mass, in which the Church in her most complete way comes together to celebrate Mass. So the entire clergy is present, in the form of priest, deacon and subdeacon, the laity is present, most of Mass is sung, incense is used, and so on.
As far as I know subdeacons are rare these days, and deacons are not common in parts of the world either. So in practice you will find that the lower role can and will be taken by the higher orders. For instance, I am a deacon, and I can also take the role of subdeacon in High Mass, but never the role of priest.
